# oracle SQL developer debug output

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQL Developer to debug code like below, the output result will be shown on debug dialog ONLY after I finish all stored procedure. Do I need to turn on some configurations ?

Thanks

```
 FOR j IN REVERSE 1..i LOOP
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(emp_tab(j).first_name);
  END LOOP;
```

log

```
Connecting to the database hr.
Executing PL/SQL: ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_DEBUG=TRUE
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( '192.168.1.4', '53475' )
Debugger accepted connection from database on port 53475.
Source breakpoint occurred at line 24 of EMP_LIST.pls.
Source breakpoint occurred at line 24 of EMP_LIST.pls.
Source breakpoint occurred at line 24 of EMP_LIST.pls.
Source breakpoint occurred at line 24 of EMP_LIST.pls.
Source breakpoint occurred at line 24 of EMP_LIST.pls.
Source breakpoint occurred at line 24 of EMP_LIST.pls.
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.DISCONNECT()
Shelli
Hermann
David
Mozhe
Sundar
Ellen
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database hr.
Debugger disconnected from database.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `DBMS_OUTPUT` to debug, you won't see any output until the process completes.  That's the way `DBMS_OUTPUT` works.

It appears you are successfully using the SQL Developer debugger, however, which is a much more effective way of debugging a stored procedure.  You are apparently setting breakpoints so you can examine the values of variables at those breakpoints.  There is no need to print the values.